# After using @pathvariable, Spring is appending all links instead of returning to expected destination

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

In the jsp, once you click on a category, it gets appended dynamically to the end of the bookRecommendation path, so you get /bookRecommendation/fiction or /bookRecommendation/biography, etc.

PROBLEM: after doing so, when I click another link, it just gets appended to the path, so bookRecommendation/aboutMe, when I just want it to take me to /aboutMe. Everything was working as expected, before I added the method containing the path variable to the controller.

```
@Controller 
public class SiteController {

@RequestMapping(path="/bookRecommendations/{category}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String displayCategoryPage(@PathVariable String category, ModelMap model) {
    List<Book> bookList = new ArrayList<>();
    bookList = bookDAO.getBooksByCategory(category);
    model.put("category", category);
    model.put("books", bookList);
    return "bookCategoryTemplate";
}

@RequestMapping("/aboutMe")
public String displayAboutMe() {
    return "aboutMe";
}
}
```

bookRecommendations.jsp:

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="dropdown">
                <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Go To...
                    <span class="caret"></span>
                </button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <c:forEach items="${categories}" var="category">
                        <li><a href="bookRecommendations/${category.name}">${category.name}</a></li>
                    </c:forEach>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

bookCategoryTemplate.jsp:

```
<div class="book-category-template">
    <h1 class="book-category-header">${category}</h1>
    <c:forEach items="${books}" var="book">
        <h3>${book.title}</h3>
    </c:forEach>
</div>
```

header.jsp

```
<header class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="bookRecommendations">Book Recommendations</a></li>
                <li><a href="aboutMe">About Me</a></li>
                <li><a href="login">Login</a>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

viewResolver.xml, if that's helpful:

```
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: can you add the jsp views

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is nothing wrong with the `controller`. you're using is a `relative` path.you need to use an `absolute` path on your server:

```
<a href="bookRecommendations/${category.name}">${category.name}</a>
```

change this to this

```
<a href="/bookRecommendations/${category.name}">${category.name}</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

It happens because the last path in your code is /bookRecommendations/{category}. So when you again press the /aboutme , the url gets appended by removing the last url i.e. in your case /{category} and adds "/bookRecommendations/aboutme.
So your solution will be just add pagecontext in the link like:

```
<a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/aboutme">Go to about me </a>
```

Happy learning!!!

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
      @RequestMapping(path="/aboutMe")
       public String displayAboutMe() {
            return "aboutMe";
       }
```